# Battery draining while car is off

Tags: battery-drain

Once I jump the car and it's running with the Positive lead on the positive terminal and the negative lead on the negative terminal I can turn the engine off and start it back up within around 10 minutes after it's been shut off. If I wait much longer than that the car will not start up as the battery is not fully charged. Now if I unhook the positive lead from the positive terminal after I turn off the car, it does not seem to drain the battery and the car will start after the lead has been attached back to the terminal.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  You've stated some conditions, left out some important ones, and haven't really asked a question.  What kind of car? How long have you had it? Is this problem new? Is the battery new/old?

Comment: So fit a battery isolator switch... have you had the battery tested? That may be one of the issues...

Comment: Could be a pletora of things, but the most common should be a wire grounding somewhere? Always disconnect the black wire, not the red one.